# Alerts does not send the metadata

Tags: 2010, alert, metadata

I have a document library with 4 columns which are of type metadata.
All 4 columns are mandatory.

When an user creates an alert, and somebody uploads a document and fills the metadata column, then in the alert, that information is not sent.

Is this possible to customize and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice would be for you to answer "No" to this and go on with your life.  However, if the customer is requiring that this information be included in the alert then prepare yourself to enter the world of pain known as SharePoint Custom Alerts.

[This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/07/customizing-alert-notifications-and-alert-templates-in-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0.aspx) should get you started on understanding what is involved in custom alerts.  The article is for SP2007 but pretty much everything in it applies to 2010 as well as they have not changed substantially.

Comment: http://www.sharemuch.com/2010/08/15/creating-custom-list-alert-templates-in-sharepoint-2010/ this seem an easy way to do it.

Comment: I was also thinking that an easier way might be to create an event receiver for the itemadding for example and then send the formatted email? in the itemadding event I should be able to access all fields.   However if the doc library has alerts enabled they would receive 2 emails-

Comment: That is merely how to change the template which you would have to do anyway when making changes. Step 6 in that article should read: "Insert Pixie Dust Here" because that is the step that will trip you up. Making fields that are not normally included in alerts appear in the alert is tricky.  To do this, you need to take more control over the alert processing logic itself which usually requires custom code that implements an IAlertNotifyHandler interface

Comment: @EstebanV. More often than not, that is what people do - simply avoid the whole Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAlertMineField and create their own emails.  They aren't as pretty, can't do digest emails, can't allow subscribe/unsubscribe or have the links back to the original list, but it is much easier and often solves the business need.

Comment: just a question, I need to estimate the time I would take to do this for a specific document library, because its the first time I would do it, how many days or hours would you estimate for these 2 options?...

Comment: There are a lot of factors I don't know so I'll assume that the person doing the coding is a veteran .Net and SharePoint developer and that the environments are already configured... in other words, absolute best case, probably 60-80 hours to modify the SharePoint Immediate Alert and another 120-160 hours to modify the Digest alert. To create a simple event handler to send an email to a set list of recipients is probably around 24-40 hours or so. Bear in mind that these are very rough estimates as there are too many unknowns to do much more.